# How do I get the entire HTML document as a string excluding some elements?

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking for a way to get the entire HTML document, excluding a few items (possibly tagged with a className called 'exclude') as a string.
I know I can grab the entire document with `document.documentElement.innerHTML`
or `document.documentElement.outerHTML`
and `document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML`

What i am still still struggling with is how do I exclude some of the nodes (such as buttons or divs or any other tags, that have a common className, before I get the innerHTML?

Comment: You'd have to remove the unwanted elements from the DOM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd probably clone the whole tree, then remove the elements you don't want:

```
var clone = document.body.cloneNode(true);
clone.querySelectorAll(".exclude").forEach(function(element) {
    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
});
var html = clone.outerHTML;
```

Note that this assumes `body`, itself, doesn't have the `exclude` class.

Example:

```js
var clone = document.body.cloneNode(true);
// Snippet-specific: Also remove the script
clone.querySelectorAll(".exclude, script").forEach(function(element) {
    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
});
var html = clone.outerHTML;
console.log(html);
```

```html
<div>
  I want this
  <div>And this</div>
</div>
<div class="exclude">
  I don't want this
  <div>Or this, since its parent is excluded</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you:) that actually works and it excludes the nodes. The question is - is it possible to preserve the styles present in header?

Comment: @MickM - I'm afraid I don't know what you mean by that. You mean you want the `style` elements in the HTML too? That's fine, just use `document.documentElement` instead of `document.body` to get the stuff in `head` as well.

Comment: My bad, that is exactly what I meant:) it worked. Thank you T.J.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use **[`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)** along with the **[`:not()` css selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not)** upon your HTML block, to exclude unwanted elements from it.

```
var content = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0]
var selection = content.querySelectorAll('*:not(.ignore)');
```

Then **just** use `outerHTML` to get the whole content from your `selection`:

```
var htmlString = selection[0].outerHTML;
```

Otherwise you can loop over the `selection` elements and for each one append its HTML to your result `string`:

```
var htmlString = "";
selection.forEach(function(el) {
  htmlString += el.innerHTML;
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
var content = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0]
var selection = content.querySelectorAll('*:not(.ignore)');

//Then log the selection content
console.log(selection[0].outerHTML);

//Or maybe loop throught the elements and get their contents
var htmlString = "";
selection.forEach(function(el) {
  htmlString += el.innerHTML;
});

console.log(htmlString);
```

**Note:**

- In this demo there were no elements with `ignore` class, but you can always put it and test.
- You can see that this will also keep all HTML elements including
  `scripts` and `styles` tags.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your response. I've just tested what you suggested and it seems like selection indeed omits the items marked with that className; however, selection[0].outerHTML returns the <head> only. am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @MickM Can you make a snippet demo? Or a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) so we can see your actual code.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late to the party but here is my contribution, I have used `chŝdk`'s idea to implement it.

---

```js
let markup = document.querySelectorAll('*:not(.exclude)')[0].innerHTML;

console.log("Data Type: " + typeof(markup));
console.log(markup);
```

```html
<center>
  <div>Hello World</div>
  <div class="exclude">Hello World [Exclude Me]</div>
  <div>Hello World</div>
  <div>Hello World</div>
  <div>Hello World</div>
  <div class="exclude">Hello World [Exclude Me]</div>
  <div class="exclude">Hello World [Exclude Me]</div>
  <div>Hello World</div>
  <div>Hello World</div>
  <div class="exclude">Hello World [Exclude Me]</div>
</center>
```